Made-for-TV movie about woman bound in the baggage section of a plane
So I recall watching a movie in the early part of the century, around 2000-2003. I believe it was a tv movie, but I have no idea what it was called. The only parts I remember are there being a woman bound in the baggage section of the plane (they're trying to find her for part/most of the movie). I believe there was also a bomb on the plane they were trying to find....the bomb may have also been in the baggage compartment if memory serves.
I just remembered something else about the movie, they figure out that her name was on the passenger list but she never got on the plane via the terminal like everyone else. From this they're eventually able to find her in the baggage compartment.

Ugh, reading "Hits" next to "Snakes on a plane" just makes me.....gag a little.

That was a joke lol

Movie identification questions must contain sufficient detail to be answerable. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions. Identification questions without an accepted answer will be deleted after 14 days.

Some facts don't match too well, but concentrating on "a woman bound in the baggage section" and "a bomb", I'd still try with 2005's Flight Plan:

The husband of aviation engineer Kyle Pratt has just died in Berlin. Now she is flying back to New York with his coffin and their six-year-old daughter Julia. Three hours into the flight Kyle awakens to find that Julia is gone! It's a big double-decker plane, so very concerned mother has a lot of territory to cover in order to find her daughter. But as Kyle fights to discern the truth, she takes matters into her own hands.

Jodie Foster is looking for her mising daughter on the plane, but all the other people increasingly doubt her sanity and if she had a daughter at all. But at the end it's revealed that her daughter was kidnapped and hidden inside the baggage section right next to a bomb.

Hmmm I don't believe this was it, I don't think there were really any big names in this one. I remember watching it late one night when I was still in high school or first year of college, at my parent's place. Which would have been 2000-2004. Thanks for the answer though, I may check that one out anyways.
